# Project Deployment in RTX Dev kit

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, wifi, rtx

After compiling a project USING AMILIE SDK RTX4140_... by RTX how to deploy the hex file in the RTX dev kit[Board].

dev kit device image
http://www.rtx.dk/RTX41xx_Development_Kit-4020.aspx

Comment: The link you included says the packahe includes *"[...]an embedded firmware development suite with download tools.*".  So that will be your answer then!  I imagine the documentation includes this information, but the site requires me to log-in to find out, so I'll leave that to you ;-)

Comment: I am looking for the AMELIE SDK COLA controller. Which is very useful to deploy the files in the RTX board i have searched for that but i am not getting that from the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use the RTX41xx_Platform_Firmware_Update_Pack to deploy hex file.